# How do you remove permanent adb authorization?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.2-jelly-bean, adb, authorization

I have a Nexus S running Cyanogen 10.1.2 (Android 4.2.2).

I require adb authorization, but I accidentally "permanently" authorized a device. How do I remove the "permanent" authorization, so that every time it asks me again?

Answer (score 7):

If your device is rooted, as it probably is with CM, you can also do this via adb:

```
adb shell rm /data/misc/adb/adb_keys
```

Depending on your build you probably have to run adb as root(1) or call the su binary(2).

(1) `adb root` or `adb kill-server; sudo $(which adb) start-server` --> `adb shell rm /data/misc/adb/adb_keys`

(2)`adb shell` --> `su` --> `rm /data/misc/adb/adb_keys`

Or delete this file with a root explorer. If you authorized more than one device open this file and remove the public key of the desired device only.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Settings -> Developer options` and under the "Debugging" section tap on the `Revoke USB debugging authorizations` option.  Keep in mind that it will remove **all** of the devices you're authorized, and you'll need to re-authorize them again.

Comment: It's not there... maybe that's another Android version?

Comment: @Lohoris What is not there? The `Developer options`?

Comment: Oh, sorry. The Developer options are there, and there is the Debugging section. However yhere's no "Revoke USB debugging authorizations", nor anything resembling anything like that in any section of the developer options.

Comment: @Chahk, indeed, there's no "Revoke USB debugging authorizations" option under "Debugging" section. What else could be done?

Comment: The "Revoke USB debugging authorizations" option is present on my Nexus 5 running Lollipop (it may be a new option in Lollipop that was not present in previous versions).

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Eventually, I checked my system variable for `ANDROID_SDK` and it was wrong (changed with the last update of Android Studio).